# How can I use Google App Engine's memcache with Quercus?

Tags: java, php, google-app-engine, memcached, quercus

On http://blog.caucho.com/?p=196, they have made Quercus run App Engine's datastore with PHP. Their source is at http://wordpress-on-quercus.appspot.com/wordpress-on-gae-quercus.zip

I would like to do something similar with their Google App Engine's memcache, preferably all in the PHP code since Quercus has the "import" command allowed within the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory;

$service = MemcacheServiceFactory::getMemcacheService();
$service->put("key", "this is the value");
echo $service->get("key"); // outputs "this is the value"
```